# Creating parameterized cursors in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, cursor

I'm Facing below error:
*`An unexpected token "(" was found following " CURSOR ". Expected tokens may include: "CURSOR". SQLSTATE=42601`*

And I'm just trying to create a simple cursor, actually the example one found [here in IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/c0053883.html).

Cursor declaration looks something like:

```
DECLARE
CURSOR c1 (max_wage NUMBER) IS
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE sal < max_wage;
```

Not sure if this is do to the version of DB2 being used or not. Can anyone suggest maybe an alternative to creating a parameterized cursor?

Comment: Do not mix SQL PL and PL/SQL syntax, and make sure you enable Oracle compatibility for the latter.

Comment: To expand on what @mustaccio said...the link you provided is for Oracle compatible PL/SQL.  You'd have to have Oracle compatibility mode turned on.   The native DB2 syntax is shown here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000937.html?lang=en-us&cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use PL/SQL syntax in DB2. This requires changes to the server environment. If you want to support the Oracle datatypes as well, the database must be created with the right settings, too. See [this article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/t0054729.html?lang=en) for more details. The summary of that article is:

1. Open a DB2 Command Window (in Administrator mode)
2. Run `db2start`
3. Run `db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=ORA`
4. Run `db2set DB2_DEFERRED_PREPARE_SEMANTICS=YES`
5. Run `db2stop`
6. Run `db2start`
7. Execute your PL/SQL statements, e.g. in a DB2 CLP (run `db2 -tv`) command window.

Note that you should run 
`SET SQLCOMPAT PLSQL;` in your DB2 CLP before trying PL/SQL. This enables using a forward slash (`/`) as a PL/SQL statement terminator. You should then obviously also then *actually* terminate your command with a forward slash :)

Here's an example taken from your link, modified to work with the default `SAMPLE` database in DB2:

```
SET SQLCOMPAT PLSQL;

DECLARE
    my_record       emp%ROWTYPE;
    CURSOR c1 (max_wage integer) IS
        SELECT * FROM employee WHERE salary < max_wage;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1(40000);
    LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO my_record;
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name = ' || my_record.firstnme || ', salary = '
            || my_record.salary);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c1;
END;
/
```

If you don't want to do all the above, then use the standard DB2 cursor syntax:

```
DECLARE [cursor name] CURSOR FOR [...]
```

...but that doesn't support parameterized cursors. To do so, I'd recommend creating a stored procedure taking the parameter. This stored procedure can then create a cursor using that parameter directly in the SQL.

Comment: Yes I tried using exact syntax from IBM docs. It did not work, I've created cursors defined in format you suggest, but it seems to only work with non parameterized cursors. I'm trying to create a parameterized cursor as per IBM doc, but no luck

Comment: Ah... when I responded, your link to the Knowledge Center wasn't working. I didn't realize you tried to use the PL/SQL syntax. You do, indeed, need to do some magic to enable that. I'll amend my answer to reflect that...